# How to determine speed (rate) in large deviation principle for geometric Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, large-deviations, mathematical-finance

By reading *Asymptotics for volatility derivatives in multi-factor rough
volatility models* by Lacombe, Muguruza and Stone, I am not familiar with the way they deduce the speed (or rate) when showing that certain functions satisfy the large deviations principle. In particular for the geometric Brownian motion, i.e. in the Black-Scholes model. When proving Corollary 3.8 they state the following result:

In the Black-Scholes model, i.e. a geometric Brownian motion with $S_0=RV(v)(0)$ with constant volatility $\xi$, we have the following small-time implied volatility behaviour:
$$
\lim_{t_\downarrow 0} \xi^2 t \log \mathbb{P} (RV(v)(0) \geq \mathrm{e}^k) = - \frac{k^2}{2}.
$$
Here, $k=\log \frac{K}{RV(v)(0)}$ is log-moneyness for some stike price $K$.

I suppose Schilder's theorem is used here, but I am not able to deduce how they determine the rate or speed for the large deviations principle.

The link to the paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11579-020-00288-5